# Filtering Chat Dialog GET results

Tags: quickblox

the following curl statement does not filter the results, I receive all Chat Dialogs for the user.

`curl -X GET -d "unread_messages_count[gt]=0" -H "QB-Token:xxxxx" https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json`

can the 'unread_messages_count' field on the Chat Dialog object be used for filtering results and with search operators?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use **unread_messages_count** as a filter because this value is calculated according to chat messages, it's not a constant field